# Scala 3: why does `inline` fix stack overflow

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3, parser-combinators

I have this code that results in a stack overflow.

```
// Lexer.Token defined elsewhere
object BadParser extends Parsers {
  import Lexer.Token
  type Elem = Token
  private def PUNCT = Token.PUNCT

 

  private def parens[T](p: Parser[T]) = PUNCT("(") ~ p ~ PUNCT(")")

 

  def expr: Parser[Any] = parens(expr) | PUNCT(".")
}
class ParensTest extends AnyFlatSpec {
  def testBad(input: String) =
    val tokens = Lexer.scan(input)
    BadParser.expr(tokens)
  "bad parser" should "not recur forever but it does" in {
    testBad("((.))")
  }
}
```

that is weird enough as it is but it gets weirder. when I try inspecting the parens(expr) like this:

```
   def expr: Parser[Any] = log(parens(expr))("parens expr") | PUNCT(".")
```

there is no longer a stack overflow.

I decided to try inlining the parens function and the argument like this:

```
inline parens(inline p... and that also fixed it.
```

the confusion for me is that the docs on inline https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/macros/inline.html say that inlining parameters shouldn't change the semantics of the function but it clearly does. What am I missing?

(my understanding of inline is that it forces the compiler to actually inline, not just give its best effort, and when you say the parameter is inline, it will inline the parameter instead of passing by value or reference)

Edit:
I'm using the Scala Parser Combinator library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By-name (also known as lazy evaluation) prevents infinite-recursion. i.e.

```scala
  private def parens[T](p: => Parser[T]) = PUNCT("(") ~ p ~ PUNCT(")")
```

The argument of operator `~` is defined [as by-name](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/blob/c6f54a0982c8116deba6788d9ed180615502c840/shared/src/main/scala/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.scala#L306C9-L306C9), so inlining would help you. However, it would not give nice result if too much call-site has been inlined.

Comment: Lazy evaluation alone does not prevent infinite recursion. It's the combination with `~` and this specific case.

Comment: that makes sense. looking more into the parser combinator source code I've noticed they do this kind of thing all over the place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite recursion when writing:

```scala
def expr = parens(expr) | PUNCT(".")
```

`expr` is calling itself before being able to call `parens`.

---

Why does it go away when inlining?

The inlined code would be as if you had written the following:

```scala
def expr = (PUNCT("(") ~ expr ~ PUNCT(")")) | PUNCT(".")
```

Now, *and this is a supposition as we don't have the full code,* `expr` calls the `~` method first which I guess does not need to evaluate `expr` in your case.

Comment: PUNCT("(") is evaluated first. the definition for `~` is found in the Scala Parser Combinator library.

Comment: so what you're saying is that it tries to evaluate `expr` before running `parens`. Inlining the code prevents this?